# Is it possible to get components' method value (means name)?

Tags: delphi

I need to get a name of a component (TButton), that is being assigned in design-time and is seen in Object Inspector (such as `Button1Click` at `Button1.OnClick` event on events tab).

I use now TypInfo unit to get method's information via `PPropInfo` and I get `OnClick` and `TNotifyEvent` strings as values, but I didn't get the `Button1Click` as string value.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string := MethodName(GetMethodProp(Button1, 'OnClick').Code);
```

Note that the method needs to be 'published'.

Comment: This also assumes that the method is implemented by the form. +1

Comment: `GetMethodProp()` returns a `TMethod`. The `TMethod.Data` field points at the object passed to the method's `Self` parameter. In 99% of cases, you can type-cast the `TMethod.Data` to `TObject` and then use that object to call `TObject.MethodName()` with `TMethod.Code` as the address, as the address will belong to that object's class. This should work in all cases, even when the event is assigned in code at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau And does it acts okay if no method assigned there or an AV would be in that case?  BTW - thanks! I will try it tomorrow at work ;)

Comment: Already checked! Everything runs fine! No AV there if nothing assigned - simply '' (empty string) there.

Comment: @notricky - But note that GetMethodProp raises an exception if the method cannot be found (wrong name, not published).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: If the method does not exist, the property could not be assigned in the first place (unless you manually assign a faulty `TMethod` to the property). `GetMethodProc()` does not validate the object passed to it, or the existence of the method being returned. Under *normal* conditions, `GetMethodProp()` either returns null, or a valid method pointer. A method does not need to be `published` in order to be assigned to a method property or gettable/settable via the property's RTTI. `MethodName()` needs it to be `published`, though.

Comment: @Remy - Thanks. I meant to say "if the property cannot be found" instead of "method".

Comment: @RemyLebeau if I need to search for a method (procedure or function) in a class (A Module or a Form) - it is possible to make it `published` and how?

Comment: By that I mean `Button1Click` event which is a part of `TForm1` - how I can find this `Button1Click` in the class of `TForm1`?

Comment: @notricky: it has to be `published` in your source code, it can't be changed to `published` at runtime. See [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If the property and assigned method are both `published`, you can use this:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

function GetEventHandlerName(Obj: TObject; const EventName: String): String;
var
  m: TMethod;
begin
  m := GetMethodProp(Obj, EventName);
  if (m.Data <> nil) and (m.Code <> nil) then
    Result := TObject(m.Data).MethodName(m.Code)
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

```
s := GetEventHandlerName(Button1, 'OnClick');
```

The `TypInfo` unit (where `GetMethodProp()` comes from) only supports `published` properties.

You have to specify the object that owns the method address because `TObject.MethodName()` iterates the object's VMT.  And the method must be `published` because `TObject.MethodName()` (which exists to facilitate DFM streaming) iterates a portion of the VMT that is filled only with the addresses of `published` methods.

If you are using Delphi 2010 or later, you can use Extended RTTI instead, which does not have the `published` limitations:

```
uses
  Rtti;

function GetEventHandlerName(Obj: TObject; const EventName: String): String;
type
  PMethod = ^TMethod;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  v: TValue;
  _type: TRttiType;
  m: TMethod;
  method: TRttiMethod;
  s: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  v := ctx.GetType(Obj.ClassType).GetProperty(EventName).GetValue(Obj);
  if (v.Kind = tkMethod) and (not v.IsEmpty) then
  begin
    // v.AsType<TMethod>() raises an EInvalidCast exception
    // and v.AsType<TNotifyEvent>() is not generic enough
    // to handle any kind of event. Basically, the Generic
    // parameter of AsType<T> must match the actual type
    // that the event is declared as.  You can use
    // TValue.GetReferenceToRawData() to get a pointer to
    // the underlying TMethod data...
    m := PMethod(v.GetReferenceToRawData())^;
    _type := ctx.GetType(TObject(m.Data).ClassType);
    for method in _type.GetMethods do
    begin
      if method.CodeAddress = m.Code then
      begin
        Result := method.Name;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

```
s := GetEventHandlerName(Button1, 'OnClick');
```

Comment: The cast to TObject is presumptuous. The `Data` pointer could refer to a class rather than an instance. Or indeed a record or a TP object.

Comment: How great it is to know. @DavidHeffernan what is the way to handle that problem?

Comment: @notricky Is it really a problem for you? You won't get any RTTI out of a TP object, but who cares about them? As for record or class type, not sure how to identify those. It would be interesting to know why you asked the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fair enough. I'm writing a `SmallClass`, where I pass itself and outer component. `Component` has its methods, which I need to find and reassign with those, that are in the instance of `self` by name. It should happen, when `Component` and `self` both have same method-names: `Component.OnClick - 'ComponentClick'` and `self.ComponentClick`. So I need to get information not only from published properties in `Component`, but also from `self`.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need to use introspection but in any case I don't see any need to know anything beyond the raw data of the method pointer. I think both answers here, whilst answering your Q well, are more complex than you need. In other words, I think you asked the wrong Q.

Comment: I have checked out that `ShowMessage(GetEventHandlerName(self,'Button1Click'))` and I got AV. My aim is to get `ShowMessage(BoolToStr(GetPropInfo(self,'Button1Click')<>nil)); //false` show me *True*! ps: `self: TForm` where `Button1Click` is a procedure, assigned to its' Button1. Have no Idea.

Comment: Oh guys, really excuse me! I forgot about the main thing `MethodAddress` that solves one part of problem. The second one already solved!